# Get Global Address List (GAL) from Exchange Server 2010 SP1 using ExchangeService

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, gal

I want to programatically (using C#) access to the Global Address List on exchange, using ExchangeService WebService. How can I do that?
Another problem: I already know how to search for a specific user. However, if that user has more than 1 email, if i search for the non-default email, he can't find it! How can I resolve this question using ExchangeService?
I saw the question [How to get contact list from Exchange Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071668/how-to-get-contact-list-from-exchange-server) but, by this way, I only can access my own address list (i want all organization address list).

Comment: I use NameResolutionCollection to search on the Exchange Server.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

http://vivekiyer.net/2010/07/17/querying-the-global-address-list-gal-via-exchange-web-services-ews/

Comment: I think this only query the information about one user. And it only search by the default email!