# How to get list of contacts and meetings from Exchange Web Services using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exchangewebservices

I searched google about this problem and I got some results:

[How to get contact list from Exchange Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071668/how-to-get-contact-list-from-exchange-server)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220498(v=exchg.80).aspx

```
// Get the number of items in the Contacts folder.
ContactsFolder contactsfolder = ContactsFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);

// Set the number of items to the number of items in the Contacts folder or 50, whichever is smaller.
int numItems = contactsfolder.TotalCount < 50 ? contactsfolder.TotalCount : 50;

// Instantiate the item view with the number of items to retrieve from the Contacts folder.
ItemView view = new ItemView(numItems);

// To keep the request smaller, request only the display name property.
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ContactSchema.DisplayName);

// Retrieve the items in the Contacts folder that have the properties that you selected.
FindItemsResults<Item>  contactItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);

// Display the list of contacts. 
foreach (Item item in contactItems)
{
    if (item is Contact)
    {
        Contact contact = item as Contact;
        Console.WriteLine(contact.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

But it seems to be a black box that only open for C# developers.

I can't see any URL or how to add WSDL file here (so I can do the same in Nodejs)

So how can I use Nodejs to get this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no NodeJS specific API.

There is a javascript version of the [EWS Managed API](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api). You may be able to get this to work in NodeJS.